# How to have save instance for orientation change when taking/uploading pic to ImageView

Tags: android, instance, android-orientation

Hi new to to Android development. Need help with maintaing the image in imageView when orientation changes. At this moment when i take a pic or upload it, it gets uploaded fine until i switch the orientation. I tried searching from other post by didn't understand well. I suppose it is something to do with save Instance. Could some one please help me with this.

```
    img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
    CharSequence[] names = { "From Gallery", "From Camera" };
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Select an option for updating your Profile Picture")
          .setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int pos) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (pos == 0) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(
                                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);    


                        startActivityForResult(i, GET_GAL_IMG);


                    } else {


                       Intent i = new Intent(
                                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                    startActivityForResult(i, GET_CAM_IMG);

                    }}}


            )
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                        }
                    }).create().show();
    }
    });}



   @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode) {

    case 2://Camera
        Log.d("take","pic");
        if (resultCode == -1) {
            String encodedImageString = null;      
            Uri selectimage=intent.getData();               
            Log.d("take","picture");
            ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);


          //Changing URI to Bitmap
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                bmp =   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectimage));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Reducing Memory
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos)) {
                byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
                encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(image,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Compression returned false");
                Log.d("Compress", "Compression returned false");
            }

           //setting Imageview as the bitmap so could send it to the canvas 
            img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);


            }



        break;
    case 1://Selecting from Gallery
        Log.d("view","pic");
        if (resultCode == -1) {

            String encodedImageString = null;
             Uri selectimage = intent.getData();
             String selectedImagepath = getPath(selectimage);
             ImageView img1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);

       //Changing URI to Bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {
            bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectimage));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         //Reducing Memory
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos)) {
            byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();
            encodedImageString = Base64.encodeToString(image,
                    Base64.DEFAULT);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Compression returned false");
            Log.d("Compress", "Compression returned false");
        }


                Log.d("view","picture");
                //setting Imageview as the bitmap so could send it to the canvas
                img1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Waqas solution is a quick fix, that is a wrong decision for different reasons.

In a few words: you are loosing you image because, when the device is rotated the current instance of Activity is lost and a new one is created. A method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) (which you can override) is called each time an activity is going to be destroyed. You can put different kinds of types to the Bundle parameter. When another instance of your Activity is created (e.g. after rotating the screen), you can use the same bundle, in which you put your previous state, to get the previously saved state. The same state can also be retrieved in onRestoreInstanceState.

In your case another problem arises: Bundle is not meant store graphics. To solve that problem you can simply put your graphics data to the memory and then read it from there. In this scenario, you could put the file name and path to the bundle. You might refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html to get some more specific information.

Comment: make sense is it possible for me to have the path in shared preference and the call it on Create?

Comment: Yes it is. When getting data form SharedPreferences instance, you could call `sharedPrefs.getString(PATH_NAME, "")` and then check if the returned is null. If it is, the path has not been saved previously, if it contains some value, the data was saved previously.

Comment: i am trying but getting Not a DRM file, opening notmally..will try to figure it out. Appreciate our help on this

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution, include the following to your relative **activity** tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

It will reuse (does not destroy and re-create activity) the screen contents when orientation changes.

Comment: what do you mean 'didn't work'? explain... in fact show how you implemented.

Comment: by putting that it doesn't hold the pic. it looses the pic. Had put this in the AndroidManifest.xml under the Activity